# What is runtime.kevent in a golang program's profile?

Tags: go, optimization, profiling

I am profiling a program where the vast majority (86%) of time is spent in two runtime functions: kevent and selectgo. I understand the select, but I don't know what kevent is (so I don't know where to start optimizing):

```
Showing top 10 nodes out of 33
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
   114.63s 65.79% 65.79%    114.63s 65.79%  runtime.kevent /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9.2/libexec/src/runtime/sys_darwin_amd64.s
    19.26s 11.05% 76.85%     35.90s 20.60%  runtime.selectgo /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9.2/libexec/src/runtime/select.go
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [network poller](https://golang.org/src/runtime/netpoll.go).
There are multiple implementations:

- [epoll](https://golang.org/src/runtime/netpoll_epoll.go) for linux
- [kevent queue](https://golang.org/src/runtime/netpoll_kqueue.go) for darwin and a bunch of others

You're seeing `kevent` due to being on Darwin.
Basically, this is time spent waiting for I/O.

Note that it's called netpoll, but it applies to file descriptors in general, so it may be network communication but it could just as well be file I/O.

Here are more details about [kqueue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) and [epoll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll).

Comment: Thanks. What non-network events could be polled for? This isn't a network program and it doesn't use any network libs.

Comment: @hunterloftis: from the go1.9 releae notes: ["The os package now uses the internal runtime poller for file I/O"](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#os)

Comment: Sorry @hunterloftis, it's not restricted to network I/O. Instead, we can broaden the definition to "file descriptors" which covers file IO as well. I've amended my answer to say so and point to further reading.